# How do I split a data frame then apply inner_join

Tags: r, split, inner-join, rbind

I have three data frames, each having about 64,000 rows and same number of 794 columns. I need to do inner_join for all 3 data frames through one common column. Due to this error "Cannot allocate vector of size  163 Mb", therefore I understand that I need to split the data frames by rows. What is the optimal number of segments to split into so as not to run out of memory when doing inner_join? If I have to split them into say 10 segments, how do I loop through the segments to do inner_join for all 3 data frames followed by a final rbind into one dataset?

Thank you.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want your final output to be a single data frame with 794x3-2 = 2380 columns and each row represents data from something like the sample IDs that must be present in all three data frames?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: Could be worth checking out the package `fst` which does a great job on memory efficience. Along with `tidyfst`. Or possibly use a `data.table` method directly? `fst` and `tidyfst` both have good info online: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/01/lightning-fa
st-serialization-of-data-frames-using-the-fst-package/
   and   
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyfst/vignettes/english_tutorial.html

Comment: and this has some join info too which may help. https://atrebas.github.io/post/2019-03-03-datatable-dplyr/

Comment: Could you please give us a MWE or example data, so that we could adapt the code. The final size of the split vector depends on the RAM available, so is dependent on your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically speaking, the optimal number of segments to split will depend on the sizes of your data and your computer's hardware specs, i.e., there's no clear answer we can give you to that question. Nevertheless, since your computer is having issues with 163Mb allocation, you can try splitting the the segments even smaller. Maybe even have only some segments loaded in R at a time. [This "Big data in R" webpage](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Esjm2186/EPIC_R/EPIC_R_BigData.pdf) might provide you with more insights.

However, this plan to split your data frames into separate segments and then inner_join all of them through a loop can be a lengthy, inefficient process. You would be trying match each segment in data frame 1 to each segment in data frame 2 and data frame 3. The computer performance will be slow like this and the computer might run out of memory again.

You will need a more resourceful approach. Try this:

Let's say here are your data frames (they're small to play with, but imagine that they are large data frames):

```r
set.seed(321)
df1 <- data.frame(id = sample(100, 50), random1 = rnorm(50), random2 = rnorm(50))
df2 <- data.frame(id = sample(100, 50), random3 = rnorm(50), random4 = rnorm(50))
df3 <- data.frame(id = sample(100, 50), random5 = rnorm(50), random6 = rnorm(50))
```

**Step 1. Remove everything you don't need to reduce the size** 
Since you are planning to inner_join, this tells me that you may have some rows that you will ultimately remove. The first step in dealing with large data is to cut down whatever you don't need.

```r
library(dplyr)

## so let's say my goal is to inner_join(by = "id")
common_id <- intersect(df1$id, df2$id) %>% intersect(df3$id)
common_id
# [1]  93  43  27  95   4  54  79  73 100  29  89  10

# keep only rows with common_id in each data frame
df1_clean <- filter(df1, id %in% common_id)
df2_clean <- filter(df2, id %in% common_id)
df3_clean <- filter(df3, id %in% common_id)
```

**Step 2. Join the data frames**
You can join them all at this point. You have a few options. **2a.** Use `inner_join()`. However, `inner_join()` might still be quite computationally intensive if you still have large data frames. **2b.** I think a less intensive approach would be to `cbind()` the three data frames (please let me know if I'm mistaken), but you should make sure the common_id are arranged in the same order in each data frame.

```r
# 2a. inner_join() approach
df_final <- inner_join(df1_clean, df2_clean, by = "id") %>% inner_join(df3_clean, by = "id")

# 2b. cbind() approach
library(magrittr)
df1_clean %<>% arrange(id)
df2_clean %<>% arrange(id) %>% dplyr::select(-id)
df3_clean %<>% arrange(id) %>% dplyr::select(-id)

df_final <- cbind(df1_clean, df2_clean) %>% cbind(df3_clean)
```

**2c.** If 2a. and 2b. still fail because your data frames are still too large, then you can try your segment method: `split()` each "cleaned" data frame into equivalent row segments, join them across data frames with `inner_join()` (or `cbind()`), and then `rbind()`. Check your data frames' and segments' data sizes (Mb) in your workspace's Environment in "Grid" view (assuming you're using RStudio). If they are still large, then break them down smaller.

**Extra**
If your R is still having issues working with your large data frames, I suggest you consider trying other programming languages (or borrow a bigger computer) to create your final data frame. R is slow or may not work when handling big data. I find bash/Unix/Terminal, for example, less likely to crash when working with big data. If you're just reorganizing/merging data files, it can be about as simple to do in bash and even faster because you don't have to load everything into RAM (see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948366/why-is-unix-terminal-faster-than-r/30948460)). I would create the data file that I need in Unix/Terminal (if feasible) and then run R to perform analyses or generate plots.

Comment: I used cbind and it works like a charm, that is a simple yet very useful solution! Thank you!