# Convert large block of binary into text in C

Tags: c, binary, bitwise-operators

I have a project in which I'm supposed to take in a file via the getchar() function and convert the binary characters within it to text.

Here is the code I have, that will produce the correct ASCII number for only one at a time. I don't know how to read in an entire text file's worth of binary and convert it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef unsigned int uint;

int strbin_to_dec(const char *);

int main(void) {



char * wbin = "01001001";
  int c = 0;

  printf("%s to ascii %d.\n", wbin, strbin_to_dec(wbin));
  printf("The character is %c", strbin_to_dec(wbin));
  return 0;
}

int strbin_to_dec(const char * str) {
  uint result = 0;
  for (int i = strlen(str) - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
    byte k = str[i] - '0';
    k <<= j;
    result += k;
  }
  return result;
}
```

The above code works when I enter exactly one character's worth of binary into the variable 'wbin', but I can't format this to accept the input from getchar() because getchar gives an int type. The above code produces the result:

```
01001001 to ascii 73.
The character is I
```

The file I'm supposed to translate looks like this:

```
0010001001001000011011110111011100100000011011110110011001110100011001010110111000100000011010000110000101110110011001010010000001001001001000000111001101100001011010010110010000100000011101000110111100100000011110010110111101110101
011101000110100001100001011101000010000001110111011010000110010101101110001000000111100101101111011101010010000001101000011000010111011001100101001000000110010101101100011010010110110101101001011011100110000101110100011001010110010000100000011101000110100001100101001000000110100101101101011100000110111101110011011100110110100101100010011011000110010100101100
01110111011010000110000101110100011001010111011001100101011100100010000001110010011001010110110101100001011010010110111001110011001011000010000001101000011011110111011101100101011101100110010101110010001000000110100101101101011100000111001001101111011000100110000101100010011011000110010100101100
01101101011101010111001101110100001000000110001001100101001000000111010001101000011001010010000001110100011100100111010101110100011010000011111100100010
0010110101010011011010010111001000100000010000010111001001110100011010000111010101110010001000000100001101101111011011100110000101101110001000000100010001101111011110010110110001100101001011000010000001010100011010000110010100100000010100110110100101100111011011100010000001001111011001100010000001000110011011110111010101110010
```

Comment: Is your question "how to read characters from a file"? In fact it looks like you don't even need to read from a file, but from a redirected `stdin`

Comment: why not use loop?

Comment: But you want this to translate only a char or a entire string?

Comment: @EugeneSh.  If I'm following you correctly then that's what I'm doing, but I can't figure out how to now translate the whole thing. It's not the same as reading a file in, from what I can tell by using a FILE object. I'm new to C, so apologies if my terminology is off.

Comment: @GonçaloBastos I need to translate that entire block of text at the bottom of my post, which is a quote from a book, but I don't know how to loop through the binary and grab what I need to provide it to the function.

Comment: I have made this code for you! Worked for me! Check what I wrote

Comment: @bannedfromquestioning I don't know if you're still looking for a good answer.  I think what you want to do is (a) declare `wbin` as `char wbin[9];`.  (b) have two nested loops.  The outer loop runs basically forever.  The inner loop runs 8 times, reading characters from standard input using `getchar()` and putting them into `wbin`.  (c) after the inner loop collects 8 characters, call `strbin_to_dec` and print out its result. (d) when `getchar` returns `EOF`, you're done.  With that code, you can run `text.exe < filetotranslate.txt`.  Then for extra credit, (e) use `fopen` to open `argv[1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a trivial task to perform simply by using bit shifting. Also instead of using `getchar`, for performance, the below uses `fread`.

This implementation uses minimal RAM (no use of malloc), no slow string parsing or math functions such as `strlen`, `strtol` or `pow`, and can handle any stream of infinite size/length, including truncated streams that are not multiples of 8 bytes.

Usage:
`./a.out < data.txt > out.txt`

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  unsigned char byte = 0;
  int bits = 0;

  for(;;)
  {
    char buffer[1024];
    int len = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), stdin);

    // if there was a read error or EOF, stop
    if (len <= 0)
      break;

    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
      switch(buffer[i])
      {
        // if a binary 1, turn on bit zero
        case '1':
          byte |= 1;
          break;

        // if a binary 0, do nothing
        case '0':
          break;

        // if antyhing else, skip
        default:
          continue;
      }

      // incrment the counter, if we dont yet have 8 bits
      // shift all the bits left by one
      if (++bits < 8)
        byte <<= 1;
      else
      {
        // write out the complete byte
        fwrite(&byte, 1, 1, stdout);

        // reset for the next byte
        bits = 0;
        byte = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  // write out any remaining data if the input was not a multiple of 8 in length.
  if (bits)
    fwrite(&byte, 1, 1, stdout);

  return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
0010001001001000011011110111011100100000011011110110011001110100011001010110111000100000011010000110000101110110011001010010000001001001001000000111001101100001011010010110010000100000011101000110111100100000011110010110111101110101
011101000110100001100001011101000010000001110111011010000110010101101110001000000111100101101111011101010010000001101000011000010111011001100101001000000110010101101100011010010110110101101001011011100110000101110100011001010110010000100000011101000110100001100101001000000110100101101101011100000110111101110011011100110110100101100010011011000110010100101100
01110111011010000110000101110100011001010111011001100101011100100010000001110010011001010110110101100001011010010110111001110011001011000010000001101000011011110111011101100101011101100110010101110010001000000110100101101101011100000111001001101111011000100110000101100010011011000110010100101100
01101101011101010111001101110100001000000110001001100101001000000111010001101000011001010010000001110100011100100111010101110100011010000011111100100010
0010110101010011011010010111001000100000010000010111001001110100011010000111010101110010001000000100001101101111011011100110000101101110001000000100010001101111011110010110110001100101001011000010000001010100011010000110010100100000010100110110100101100111011011100010000001001111011001100010000001000110011011110111010101110010
```

Output:

```
"How often have I said to youthat when you have eliminated the impossible,whatever remains, however improbable,must be the truth?"-Sir Arthur Conan Doyle, The Sign Of Four
```

Answer (score -1):

Read in all the input from the file, and pass in 8 chars at a time to a converter function to return a char. Each char is 8 bits, and each character in the file represents 1 bit.

```
char string_to_character(char * in)
{
  char ret = 0;
  int i;
  for(i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    if(in[i] == '1')
      ret += 1 << (7 - i);

  return ret;
}
```

This function will decode each 8 chars from the file into one character. Simply call the function with an offset of 8 chars for the entire input string and save the result somewhere.

EDIT: Be sure to include and link math library math.h.
EDIT 2: Should be >= not >

For looping...

Say you have the entire file as one long string.

```
int num_chars = (sizeof(input) / sizeof(char)) / 8;
int i;
char output[num_chars + 1];
for(i = 0; i < num_chars; i++)
   output[i] = string_to_character(input + (i * 8));

printf("%s", output);
```

This was the result I got from the program

"How often have I said to youthat when you have eliminated the impossible,whatever remains, however improbable,must be the truth?"-Sir Arthur
Conan Doyle, The Sign Of Four

EDIT: left bitshift vs pow

Comment: Not only does this need to read the entire file in, using `pow` to do what could be done with a simple `OR` and left shift is just insane.

Comment: @Geoffrey Fair, left shift is more efficient by a long shot. Problem requires reading entire file in though, that's unavoidable.

Comment: Reading the entire file is needed yes, but you do not need to be buffering the entire file into RAM, nor can you when you're reading from `stdin` as the OP asked for. The length of the input is not determinate and could be infinite. See my answer.

Comment: @Geoffrey Putting it all in ram versus reading iteratively is generally not a big issue. Could be tweaked to run iteratively, but it will certainly run much slower because disk access times are hundreds of times slower then ram access. I assume the input file is not many gigabytes big and will destroy ram.

Comment: It's bad practice, especially if you're writing a tool that may be used by the masses. If you expect to be able to read the entire input in from `stdin` before processing it and someone later wants to use this as part of a pipe operation (ie, `cmd | binToByte | cmd`) it becomes impossible.  It certainly will not be slower either as we are processing it in 1KB chunks allowing the OS to read ahead and pre-cache data. If anything it will be faster as we avoid the need to malloc buffers and determine the file size.

Comment: @Geoffry No malloc being used. Overflowing the stack is a possibility, but I assume this answer is good enough for the user asking. His sample was not a huge file. Miss me with best practice, create the best tool for the problem not the best tool for every problem. No need to over complicate anything.

Comment: *it will certainly run much slower because disk access times are hundreds of times slower then ram access* Say what?  You're going to have to read the file off of the disk no matter what.  It's a question of read-from-stdin-into-malloc'ed-region, convert-from-binary-out-of-malloc'ed-region, versus convert-from-binary-off-of-stdin.  I can't see the latter not being a win.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948366/why-is-unix-terminal-faster-than-r) and [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948366/why-is-unix-terminal-faster-than-r/30948460#30948460).

Comment: @Steve Summit Stdin is a file read. Instead of repeatedly reading over the file, load the entire file into ram if its small enough. This is faster. Also, no malloc. The entire data is dynamically stack allocated. Regardless it needs to be put into memory. Reading the file repeatedly off disk and loading into ram is slower than loading all initially into ram.

Comment: Why do you have to read over the file repeatedly? I would think a single pass would do.

Comment: A single pass would put it all in memory. Thats what I did. If you do not put it all in memory, you by definition will need to access the disk repeatedly, because that is how computer memory hierarchy works.

Comment: How can a single pass read put it all in memory, `stdin` may be a stream of infinite size, it may not be from a file, it could be fed via a socket, or some other application via a pipe. We also never re-read anything we just load chunks into a small buffer, parse them IN RAM and then move onto the next chunk. There is no re-reading, or re-accessing the disk. Please learn what `stdin` is and how `fread` actually works on modern  operating systems. Suggested keywords "read ahead"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-handles - "During console creation, the system creates these handles. Initially, STDIN is a handle to the console's input buffer, and STDOUT and STDERR are handles of the console's active screen buffer"... note `BUFFER`, not `FILE`.

Answer (score -1):

This is a function made by me! I dont know if you use the file as a parameter of execution like: ./text.exe -f binary.txt! But I dont add entries to the program! I has defined the file by my self!

I have created a function to write to a file, but if you want to use the command like ./text.exe -f binary.txt > translatedfile.txt you can simply remove the function write_to_file! Dont forget to remove the prints that you dont want because the parameter ">" will print everything!

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void binary_to_char(char *str);
void write_to_file(char *text);

int main(void)
{

    printf("Getting line from file\n");

    FILE *file;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t stringLength;

    file = fopen("binary.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR]: cannot open file -- binary.txt");
        perror("");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((stringLength = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1)
    {
        printf("\n%s", line);
        binary_to_char(line);
    }
    free(line);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}

void binary_to_char(char *str)
{
    char binary[9];
    char *text = malloc((strlen(str) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    char c;
    int pos = 0;
    int letter_pos = 0;
    printf("\nConverting into characters\n");
    for (size_t j = 0; j < strlen(str) / 8; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            binary[i] = str[pos];
            pos++;
        }
        c = strtol(binary, 0, 2);
        text[letter_pos] = c;
        letter_pos++;
    }
    printf("\n%s\n", text);
    write_to_file(text);
    free(text);
}

void write_to_file(char *text)
{
    printf("\nContent saved to translatedfile.txt\n");
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("translatedfile.txt", "w+");
    fprintf(fp, "%s", text);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

**Content of File binary.txt:**

```
001000100100100001101111011101110010000001101111011001100111010001100101011011100010000001101000011000010111011001100101001000000100100100100000011100110110000101101001011001000010000001110100011011110010000001111001011011110111010101110100011010000110000101110100001000000111011101101000011001010110111000100000011110010110111101110101001000000110100001100001011101100110010100100000011001010110110001101001011011010110100101101110011000010111010001100101011001000010000001110100011010000110010100100000011010010110110101110000011011110111001101110011011010010110001001101100011001010010110001110111011010000110000101110100011001010111011001100101011100100010000001110010011001010110110101100001011010010110111001110011001011000010000001101000011011110111011101100101011101100110010101110010001000000110100101101101011100000111001001101111011000100110000101100010011011000110010100101100011011010111010101110011011101000010000001100010011001010010000001110100011010000110010100100000011101000111001001110101011101000110100000111111001000100010110101010011011010010111001000100000010000010111001001110100011010000111010101110010001000000100001101101111011011100110000101101110001000000100010001101111011110010110110001100101001011000010000001010100011010000110010100100000010100110110100101100111011011100010000001001111011001100010000001000110011011110111010101110010
```

Comment: This answer while works is extremely poor. Not only does it need to read the entire input first (useless for reading `stdin` and limits the input size), it also uses `malloc`, `strlen`, and `strol` simply to do what could be done with a simple bitshift operation.

Comment: @Geoffrey Okay, I just tryed to help!